# Use a sharepoint list as a repeating section in another list form

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath

I have a SharePoint List, e.g List A with few column. I have another list B with few columns. I am designing an InfoPath form off of List A and I want to display few columns from List B as a repeating table/section in the infopath form. The problem is, InfoPath List form doesn't allow repeating section in form design.

Can anyone recommend a possible workaround for this issue?